# Routing depending on optional action value in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Being rather new to ASP.MVC I'm looking for a solution to the following routing problem.

I want these Url's to lead to the shown pages:

**/Member/123/A+Strange+Username** -> page with members details
**/Member/123** -> as above
**/Member/Connections/123** -> page with list of members connections
**/Member/Connections/123/A+Strange+Username** -> as above
**/Member/Comments/123** -> page with list of members comments
**/Member/Comments/123/A+Strange+Username** -> as above

The username should be ignored but will be appended to links to help search engines.

I have tried with the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("MemberPage", "Member/{id}/{*name}", new { controller = "Member", action = "Details", id = "" });
routes.MapRoute("MemberAction", "Member/{action}/{id}/{*name}", new { controller = "Member", action = "Details", id = "" });
```

But it seems it always defaults to the first route, and then gets an error since "Connections" or "Comments" is invalid id's for the Details controller.

Is there a way to switch route depending on the type of the id-value, or another way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help if you add a route constraint to the {id} both routes.

```
routes.MapRoute("MemberPage", "Member/{id}/{*name}",
      new { controller = "Member", action = "Details", id = "" },
      new { id=@"\d+" });
routes.MapRoute("MemberAction", "Member/{action}/{id}/{*name}",
      new { controller = "Member", action = "Details", id = "" },
      new { id=@"\d+" });
```

This way, it won't try to map "Comments" to {id} in the first route and will fall through to the second one which should work fine with that URL.